# Non existing value for foreign key in django

Tags: django

I would like know if I can make django accept values for foreign key that doesn't exist in the column referenced.

The problem in the business logic is that a model can point to the phone number of a user that doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 0):

You could, but it's more a referential problem and you're likely to get database integrity issues if you do that.

Djang even allows you to set the `on_delete` method to be `DO_NOTHING` specifically so you can end up in this kind of situation, but it also warns  against it ...

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DO_NOTHING

> If your database backend enforces referential integrity, this will
> cause an IntegrityError unless you manually add an SQL ON DELETE
> constraint to the database field.

A better solution would be to add an extra field to the `User` model to indicate whether they are active yet, add the record as `inactive` and build suitable logic around that.

Don't try and work around database integrity constraints though, it almost certainly won't end well and will be confusing to future maintainers.